# remove relation one-to-many nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am new to typeorm and nestjs, however I wonder if it is possible to remove a one-to-many realtion for example when I make the relation it looks like this:

```
id | title | relationId
1    test        2
```

however I would like to remove a relation back to original state like:

```
id | title | relationId
1     test    [null]
```

And then later upadate that with a new one-to-many relation like:

```
id | title | relationId
1     test      4
```

I am not sure if that is even possible to be honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass `null` as the relation in a save call to clear the relation from the record.

```
myRepository.save({ id: 1, title: 'test', relation: null })
```

Just note that your column must be nullable, or TypeORM (and your database) will enforce that the `relationId` has a value. You would set that up with something like:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Relation, (myEntity) => myEntity.relations)
relation: Relation | null
```